How to create a union of two tables with a partially nullable column
In the following minimal example, foo is a STRING in table a. In table b it's NULL.
WITH
  a AS (
  SELECT
    "ax" AS x,
    "bla" AS foo),

  b AS (
  SELECT
    "bx" AS x,
    NULL AS foo)

SELECT * FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM b

BigQuery derived the type of foo in b as INT64, so the query fails:
Column 2 in UNION ALL has incompatible types: STRING, INT64 at [14:1]

Sure, in this minimal example, one can replace NULL AS foo with CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS foo), to make it work.
But in my actual application, the schemas of the tables to merge are quite complex (multiple nested structs, etc.), and it would be great if there is a solution that does not require me to cast every NULL to a type. Is there a way to leave the type of foo in b open, such that it specializes to whatever it required (STRING in that case) when the UNION ALL happens?
